# Need to remove blank space above first option in select before selection is changed

Tags: html, html-select

I have this problem with a select element where there is a blank space above the first `option` when the select is opened but only before another option is selected. Once a selection is made the blank space is no longer there(see second image below)if the select is reopened, which is the behaviour I want by default. I need to make it so the user must make one of two choices and cannot leave it false by selecting the blank option. Here are some screen shots:

[image]
[image]

This is the html

```
    <form-group ng-init="item.isLeader = item.isLeader === undefined ? false : item.isLeader">
      <label class="col-sm-4">Type</label>
      <div class="col-sm-7">
      <select class="form-control" class="col-sm-7" ng-model="item.isLeader">
      <option ng-selected="!item.isLeader" ng-value="false">Bon Coup</option>
     <option ng-selected="item.isLeader" ng-value="true">Leader</option>
    </select>
   </div>
  </form-group>
```

Is there a way of doing this is Angularjs. I would like to fix it just in the HTML template without using controller or `ng-options`to solve it if possible. Any help appreciated thanks!

Comment: The blank space is the `false`

Comment: works fine in chrome: https://jsfiddle.net/ajwjg22h/

Comment: I know. I want it so that the user must make a choice. False cannot be an option.

Comment: It may work in isolation in jsfiddle but it's not working in my app and I'm viewing in Chrome.

Comment: The first option is already selected by default(see first image above). I just don't want the user to be able to select the empty option making it default to `false`. I want them only to be able to make one choice or the other and if they don't choose it will stay at the default first choice.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Create a demo with the problem. your code works fine. http://plnkr.co/edit/m0mbagMwJSZUn0n31X6r?p=preview